# Spring Integration - Use original payload after publishing xml payload

Tags: spring-integration

I am learning SI 3.0. There is a flow in which original payload is transformed to XML string and then published on a queue. There is a requirement to persist some required information to database after successfully publishing on the queue. So I need to retrieve the original payload and persist. I can use  to store the object. Whats the best approach to use to persist the data in this case.

```
<int:chain input-channel="inceptionProcessorChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.sbl"/>
    <int:transformer ref="sblOutputTranslator" method="convert"/>
    <int:transformer ref="sblToXml" method="doTransform"/>
</int:chain>
```

I dont want to store the payload in header as its a heavy object.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It's only a reference, so I am not sure why you are concerned about keeping it as a header (unless you are persisting the message or transporting it over a network).

Add

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="saveIt" expression="payload" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

to your chain.

You can store it someplace else (e.g. by invoking a service-activator) and retrieve it later but it's functionally (and memory-wise) no different than keeping a reference to the original payload in a header.